# Invalid time interval & in my basic shell that I am creating

Tags: c, shell

So I am creating a basic shell. I fork and call execvp. If a command (i.e. `sleep 5m &`) has "&" in the end, my parent process doesn't wait for the child. Otherwise it does. So in the child process, I call `execvp(args[0],args)`. If args is `sleep 5m &`, how can I remove the & so that the child process only reads `sleep 5m` and not the & because I am guessing that is where the issue is coming from.

```
if(pid==0){
   execvp(args[0],args);
}
//if parent process
if(!(strcmp(args[0],"&")==0)){
  wait(0);
}
```

EDIT: I was able to solve it by using a flag, if the user input included &, I turned on the flag. Now it works

Comment: Just describing the code in prose is almost never clear enough (prose, unlike code, can be interpreted in multiple ways). Please show a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code that illustrates the problem.

Comment: What is the code that you have written??? Please post at least the snippet of code in which you are facing the problem. That way, we could help you better

Comment: A simple search is a very bad idea. What if the `&` is escaped or in a string literal? You need to parse the input properly. The actual execution of statements is the lesser job in designing an interpreter (which a shell is).

Comment: Yes; not all syntax in the original command line becomes argument material for the child process! For instance `> file` turns into a redirection of standard output and not the arguments `">"` and `"file`". And not all the command line material that *does* become argument material does so verbatim. For instance `$VAR` must turn into the expanded value of a variable (possibly multiple arguments, if unquoted) and so on.  Basically the shell is a language which parses,  expands and interprets command lines, and synthesizes command invocations.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *idx = strrchr(cmd, '&');
if(idx != NULL)
    *idx = '\0';
```

find the last& in the string and replaces it by '0' (end of string)

Comment: oops - too much c++ programming tx

Comment: I understand what this is doing but am not sure where to write it. I am passing args[0], args into execvp. Is there a way to remove '&' from the args itself.

Comment: you should not modify args. Copy (use strcpy) the string you want to change